# Ubuntu 12.04 virtual machine Windows 7 networking

Tags: vmware

I installed VMware workstation (9.0) on my Windows 7 PC, and installed Ubuntu 12.04. I got everything else working except that I cannot seem to get networking going in the ubuntu box. In the VMware settings, I tried both NAT and Bridged connections (with "Replicate physical networking connection state" and without it).

My Windows PC's ifconfig looks like this:

```
Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . : something.net
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::7598:cf46:98b:5b
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 10.155.10.214
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.252.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 10.155.8.1

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet1:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e870:d3cf:21b9:1
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.237.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :

Ethernet adapter VMware Network Adapter VMnet8:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e0a0:d219:ed1b:1
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.126.1
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
```

And the ifconfig (linux) looks like this:

```
eth0      Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:0c:29:b6:6a:8d  
          inet6 addr: fe80::20c:29ff:feb6:6a8d/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:653 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:2127 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:52484 (52.4 KB)  TX bytes:223515 (223.5 KB)
          Interrupt:19 Base address:0x2000 

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:16436  Metric:1
          RX packets:279 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:279 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:23884 (23.8 KB)  TX bytes:23884 (23.8 KB)
```

My /etc/network/interfaces file looks like this:

```
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

Regards
Deepak

Answer (score 0):

Interface eth0 is not configured in Ubuntu.

Did you install Ubuntu Server or Ubuntu Desktop?

If Ubuntu Server then /etc/network/interfaces should include the following stanza.

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet dhcp
```

After adding this, run `sudo ifup eth0`.

If Ubuntu Desktop then use "network-indicator | Edit Connections..." to configure a Wired Connection.